# Hover effect on links doesnt work

Tags: css

***EDITED:

"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." – Marc B, Márton Molnár, LinkinTED, Anonymous, Joshua Moore"

The code is provided; the problem is specified; theres a clear problem... how the heck do i need to describe it more than i did, if i don't understand what's the problem.

***END

Please help!

Two examples:

1) 
css:

```
        .link-with-popup {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font: normal 11px tahoma;
    }

    .link-with-popup:hover {
        z-index: 200;
    }

    .link {
        background: #E0EAF1;
        padding: 10px 0;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link:hover {
        background: #c4dae9;
    }
    .aa {
        color:#FF00FF;
    }
    /* The problem */
    .link:hover + .popup {
        display: block;
    }
    /* /The problem */
    .popup {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 400px;
        bottom: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .popup:hover {
        display: block;
    }

    .popup .box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 130px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #505050;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/densssky/s0cg4pvu/)

2) 
css:

```
    .link-with-popup {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font: normal 11px tahoma;
    }

    .link-with-popup:hover {
        z-index: 200;
    }

    .link {
        background: #E0EAF1;
        padding: 10px 0;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link:hover {
        background: #c4dae9;
    }
    .aa {
        color:#FF00FF;
    }
    /* The problem */
    .aa:hover + .popup {
        display: block;
    }
    /* /The problem */
    .popup {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 400px;
        bottom: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .popup:hover {
        display: block;
    }

    .popup .box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 130px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #505050;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
```

[jsfiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/densssky/4vkLdLh3/)

In the first one, the hover effect is working fine, but in the second it's not. I can't understand why. It should effect on links as well...

Please help

Comment: I strongly recommend you consider changing the title of your question to something more descriptive of your question.

Comment: yes, you're right. hope it's better

Comment: I replaced `.aa:hover + .popup` with `.link:hover + .popup` , then its working, exactly what is the problem?

Comment: look at my first jsfiddle, pal. Ilpo Oksanen provided the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you're targeting `.aa` instead of `.link`. `.aa` is a child of `.link` and `.popup` is the next sibling of `.link`. The `+` selector selects next sibling. `.popup` is not the next sibling of `.aa`, which is why you should use `.link:hover+.popup` as your selector:

```
    .link:hover + .popup {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear. But can you tell me, why when I targeting elements it's not working? here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/densssky/znmhufcg/